# Setting Event to Expire Using Custom Metabox

Tags: metabox, date-time

Working on a real estate website and setting Open House dates and times using drop downs in a Custom Meta Box. Example drop down below:

```
<select name="sale_listing_open_house1_start_day" id="sale_listing_open_house1_start_day">  
        <option value="monday" <?php selected( $selected, 'Monday' ); ?>>Monday</option>  
        <option value="tuesday" <?php selected( $selected, 'Tuesday' ); ?>>Tuesday</option>  
        <option value="wednesday" <?php selected( $selected, 'Wednesday' ); ?>>Wednesday</option>  
        <option value="thursday" <?php selected( $selected, 'Thursday' ); ?>>Thursday</option>
        <option value="friday" <?php selected( $selected, 'Friday' ); ?>>Friday</option>  
        <option value="saturday" <?php selected( $selected, 'Saturday' ); ?>>Saturday</option>
        <option value="sunday" <?php selected( $selected, 'Sunday' ); ?>>Sunday</option>  
    </select>
```

Let's say there's a drop down for the end day, month, date and time ... Is there any way to format this so that the Open House will expire once the date/time has passed what was specified in the drop down?

Comment: What do you mean by expire? That the post is deleted/changes status?

Comment: Currently, the post is set to display a badge with the date/time of the open house using the tag "open house" in conjunction with a custom field that display's if the post has_tag(). Ideally, I'd like that to go away once the date set in the drop down passes.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Post Expirator plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-expirator/).

> The Post Expirator plugin allows the user to set expiration dates for both posts and pages. There is a configuration option page in the plugins area that will allow you to seperataly control whether or not posts/pages are either deleted or changed to draft status.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to change the post status... just have a function that maybe checks the date used in the dropdown and hooks into delete_post_meta to remove the Open House info. Maybe a nightly cron job or something...

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure to clearly understand what you want but why won't you use a Javascript timer to "lock" it after a certain time is passed?

Otherwise, you'll have to use Database/PHP and check the expiration date. I do not see how you can do otherwise ( with the given information ).